# Taylor series for $\ln(a-x)$ centered at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Hey can someone help with finding the Taylor series for $\ln(a-x)$

I have tried using induction to determine the $f^{n}(x)$

$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(a-x)}$$

$$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{(a-x)^2}$$

$$f'''(x)=\frac{-2}{(a-x)^3}$$

My guess for the sum is

$$f^n(x)=(-n)!(a-x)^{-n}$$

induction proof $n=1$

$$f^1(x)=(-1)!(a-x)^{-1}=-\frac{1}{(a-x)}$$

for $n+1$

$$f^{n+1}(x)=(-n+1)(a-x)^{-(n+1)}=-\frac{n+1!}{(a-x)^{n+1}}$$

I was told the answer is

$$\ln(a)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{-n}a^{-n}x^n$$

can anyone help with me with the next part?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your derivatives have the wrong sign: the all keep the same sign. Perhaps you forgot to multip[ly by the inner derivative, which is $\;-1\;$ ?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Notice that

$$\ln(a-x)=\ln a+\ln\left(1-\frac xa\right)$$

Comment: could you explain what the hint has to do with the Taylor series

Comment: The Taylor series of $\ln(1-y)$ is well known $$\ln(1-y)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y^n}{n}$$

Answer (score 2):

The approach you are taking is not the easiest way, but it will work.

$f(x) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {c_n (x-a)^n}{n!}\\
c(0) =f(a), c_n = f^{(n)}(a)$

$f(0) = \ln a$

$f^{(n)}(x) = -(n-1)! (x-a)^{-n}$ (it should be $(n-1)!$ and not $(n+1)!$, check out $f'''(x)$ in your work above)

$f^{(n)}(0) = -(a)^{-n} (n-1)!\\
\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} = \frac{-a^{-n}}{n}\\
f(x) = \ln a + \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} -\dfrac {x^n}{na^n}$

The other way to do it.

$f'(x) = - \frac1{(a-x)^{-1}}$ and recoginize the that this is the sum of a geometric series.

$f'(x) = -\sum \frac{x^n}{a^n}$

And integrate:
$f(x) = f(0) -\sum \frac{x^n}{na^n}$

Answer (score 1):

You've already been commented/answered, but here's an idea: for

$$|x|<a\iff \left|\frac xa\right|<1\;:\;\;\;\frac1{a-x}=\frac1a\frac1{1-\frac xa}=\frac1a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac xa\right)^n$$

Now, we know that within the convergence interval the series can be both differentiated and integrated termwise, so for $\;|x|<a\;$  we get

$$-\log(a-x)=\int\frac{dx}{a-x}=\frac1a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{a^n}\int x^n\;dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{a^{n+1}(n+1)}\implies$$

$$\log(a-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n\,a^n}$$